# cell height depending on a label text

Tags: ios, uitableview

I get the object from CoreData like this `self.name = [[abc anyObject] valueForKey:@"name"]`
and display it:

```
cell.nameLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",self.name];
cell.nameLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
cell.nameLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
```

How can I get the correct height for my cell to return it in
 `- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the solution:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CGSize constraintSize = CGSizeMake(286.0f, CGFLOAT_MAX);
    UIFont *theFont  = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0f];
    CGSize theSize;

    if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 7.0)
    {
        CGRect frame = [[self.mArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] boundingRectWithSize:constraintSize options:(NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin | NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading) attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:theFont} context:nil];
    theSize = frame.size;
    }
    else
    {
        theSize = [[self.mArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] sizeWithFont:theFont constrainedToSize:constraintSize lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
    }

    return theSize.height;
    }
```

Also in `- (UITableViewCell )tableView:(UITableView )tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` I used `cell.label.numberOfLines = 0`

If you are using more than one Label in row - in `CGSizeMake(286.0f, CGFLOAT_MAX)` use lower value than 286.0f (for example 150.0f)

Answer (score 1):

Just implement a static method in your UITableViewCell class that is able to calculate cell height basing on provided string and a width. Cell should know how it is constructed and how much space it will occupy.

For example:

```
+ (CGFloat)heightForWidth:(CGFloat)width text:(NSString *)text {

    CGFloat height = ... ;

    return height;
}
```

Comment: I didn't understand it. I Have my own class for cell, and how I get 'CGFloat height = '?

Comment: You accidentally the whole interesting part.

Comment: If your cell contains only one multiline label this method would looke sth like this (just use the same label font and line breaking mode that you use for your label:`+ (CGFloat)cellHeightForTitle:(NSString *)title width:(CGFloat)width {
    CGFloat height = 0.0;
    height += 2 * verticalMargin;

    height += [title sizeWithFont:font
                constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(width - 2*sideMargin, MAXFLOAT)
                    lineBreakMode:lineBreakMode].height;

    return height;
}`

Answer (score 0):

Try to disable auto layout in your storyboard and then call sizeToFit.

```
cell.nameLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",self.name];
cell.nameLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
cell.nameLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
[cell.nameLabel sizeToFit];
```